# Migrating an old client/server app to localhost (binding to localhost)

Tags: networking, network-programming

I have a network application with a client and a server, each one on different device and has an IP. If I move both of them to the same device and localhost, they should work normally but the question is, if I send a request from client 
does it go to the NIC and outside network then come back to localhost? Or does it immediately go to the localhost without passing to NIC?

Answer (score 0):

All traffic to localhost (127.0.0.1) will be handled internally and will not be sent externally by default.